# UNIX programming linux

Tags: linux, unix

Hi am trying to extract the part of the line after a decimal.
My input line is 
A-b-2.0.2-c

I want to use sed to get the output as
2.0.2-c

Can some one help me out?

Comment: Hi, please share what have you tried so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not perfect, but working:

```
echo "A-b-2.0.2-c" | sed -r -n -e 's/^[^0-9]+([0-9.]+.*)$/\1/p'
```

The issue is that the `sed` command does *not* support non-greedy matching which is why you have to use an exclusion pattern for the leading part of the string. For a more precise matching pattern you'd have to use some other tool.

Answer (score 0):

This is definetly an exercise sed is made for. With the information that you provide following would work:

```
$ sed 's/A-b-//' input.txt
```

There is also a bash way to do it:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

input="A-b-2.0.2-c"
echo ${input/A-b-/}
```

would also extract the line after the decimal.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But the line I have is a sample.....My decimal may occur at any point. This is actually my folder name....From this folder name I need to extract the substring of the folder name from decimal till end of line. Can you help me out?

Comment: You should add that information to your question. This way future readers will have that in mind when thinking about solutions!